# Customing the Edit Node Experience?

Tags: nodes

Use case: I've created a custom content type with a variety of fields and widgets.

I want some privaledged users to be able to edit these nodes, but not get distracted by several fields they will not need.

So to provide a slimmer version of the edit mode...is it something I should do with Views, or perhaps create a custom tpl file?

Comment: [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) might be a simpler solution

Comment: Also try the [Simplify module](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplify).

Comment: could be done with [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) as well